# Login page and sign up page to save user details not working

Tags: android, authentication

I am new to android. I am trying to create a Login page and save user details in the database. The signup activity works fine. But when i click the login button it gives the following error:                                                                       **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**
Please can someone help.

DatabaseUserDetails:

```
public class DatabaseUserDetails extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userDetailsDB.db";

private static final String TABLE = "userdeatils";

public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";
public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "emailid";
public  SQLiteDatabase db;

public DatabaseUserDetails(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE_CLASS = "CREATE TABLE  " + TABLE + "(" +
            COLUMN_USERNAME + " " + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_PASSWORD + " " + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT)";
    Log.d("onCreate",CREATE_TABLE_CLASS);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CLASS);
}

public void insertEntry(String username,String password,String emailid )
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, username);
    values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD,password);
    values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, emailid);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE,null,values);
    Log.d("insertEntry",username);
    Log.d("insertEntry",password);
    db.close();
}
public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName)
{
    Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE, null, " username=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
    {
        cursor.close();
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PASSWORD));
    cursor.close();
    return password;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
 mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String struserName = mUsername.getText().toString();
            String strpassword = mPassword.getText().toString();
            DatabaseUserDetails dbuserdeatils = new DatabaseUserDetails(getBaseContext(),null,null,1);
            String storedPassword = dbuserdeatils.getSinlgeEntry(struserName);
            if(strpassword.equals(storedPassword)) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Welcome home"+struserName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Go to homepage
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomePageActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Username and passwords do not match",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting Null pointer exception for SQLiteDatabase, you have'nt created an instance for it.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
```

or

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Add these statement before db.query() in getSingleEntry() method.

Comment: Thanks that worked. But i am trying to retrieve the username and password so that user can login but its retrieving email instead of password. I checked my code it looks fine to me. can u please help?

Comment: In inserEntry() method you will see you have inserted emailId in COLUMN_PASSWORD column values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, emailid);

Comment: yeah i corrected that but still giving me the same error

Comment: hey got it. Just had to clean build my project and clear cache data. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The query in `getSinlgeEntry(String userName)` may not be returning what you need. For queries, the method call is as follows:

```
query(String table,
      String[] columns,
      String selection,
      String[] selectionArguments,
      String groupBy,
      String having,
      String orderBy)
```

So yours should be:

```
query(TABLE,
      new String[] {COLUMN_USERNAME, COLUMN_PASSWORD},
      COLUMN_USERNAME + " = ? " ,
      new String[] {userName},
      null,
      null,
      null)
```

This says, return from my table the username & password where the userName value is the same as the userName that was sent in from your method call. Try this & let me know in the comments below if you need more help.

Comment: i did as u said. But i am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

that is the usage of this code :

`public  SQLiteDatabase db;`

does this code initialized？

when you call `getSinlgeEntry()`,the "db" in

`Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE, null, " username=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);`

actually means this.db ~~

but this.db == null in your code ~~